# Setting up Different Layouts for Each Product Category and Subcategory

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic

how do I create different layouts for each product category and subcategory in Woocommerce?
If I change settings, they seem to affect every category and product page, but I want to make sure they are all distinct.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Woocommerce follows WordPress's native template hierarchy system.

To create a template file to be used for a specific category, use this file naming scheme:

```
taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php
```

So, for Woocomerce categories, this will be:

```
taxonomy-product_cat-{category_name}.php
```

You can create one of those files for each category that you want to have a different appearance from the default category.

You need to put your custom Woocommerce templates in `your_theme_directory/woocommerce`.

Note - the above method to your question will mean 'hardcoding' (the category names will be attached to the file names), but as long as the person who will be creating new categories is always also a developer who can create the extra files, then no problem.

Comment: Awesome thanks, even though it's an off topic question.  This is a really popular plugin so a useful answer.